# How do we compute FX volatility for any given FX strike and time to maturity?

Tags: volatility, fx, volatility-surface

I want to implement a function which is passed two inputs: a strike and a time to maturity (which can be arbitrary within a specified range) and returns an FX volatility for this strike and maturity from a volatility surface estimated from FX data.

To give you context, I was given volatilies for 10delta put & call, 25delta put and call, ZDS/ATM for various tenors (O/N, 1W, 1Y etc). So using these and expiries I calculated my strike prices (using flat yield curve for both currencies) for each of the delta call and puts. Now I am asked to create a function to interpolate volatilities for any strike price and expiry

Comment: This is mission impossible, as an FX forward does not involve a volatility.

Comment: Actually, I would like to edit the question and say just any Strike and Time to Maturity

Comment: Just to give you context, I was given volatilies for 10delta put & call, 25delta put and call, ZDS/ATM for various tenors (O/N, 1W, 1Y etc). So using these and expiries I calculated my strike prices (using flat yield curve for both currencies) for each of the delta call and puts. Now I am asked to create a function to sort of backsolve for volatilities for any strike price and expiry

Comment: Please see if you like my edits or if you would like to revert to previous question.

Comment: @noob2. Thanks sounds very clear now based on your edit.